# Gracefully Pause or Resume SVG Animation using Rum or Reagent in ClojureScript

Tags: animation, svg, clojurescript, reagent, rum

How do you pause a running SVG animation using `<animateTransform>` element inside an SVG without losing the animation state?

Setting `animation-play-state: paused;` on either the animating element, or the parent element has no effect. Changing the repeatCount from `indefinite` to `0`, loses the animation state.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late, but here is how to do it in vanilla javascript: https://codepen.io/jjdewitt/pen/XJRqNK?editors=1010

You need to call `yourSvgElement.pauseAnimations();` on the SVG Element